# Is it possible in a bash script to change its content while it's running?

Tags: linux, windows, bash, shell

**Short version:**
Is it possible in a bash script to change its content while it's running?

**Long version:**
I have a bash script that i want to change it's EOL from CRLF'\r\n' to LF'\n' while it's running. At the moment, what i could manage to do so far is to put this line on top of the script:

```
sed -i -e "s/\r$//g; s/^sed -i -e/#sed -i -e/g" $(basename $0); echo "Rerun again.." ; exit 0;
```

But it's unpractical for sure.

I was thinking of that When the script runs in the first line it creates a subshell and puts the content of the current shell there, do some changes and put it back in the upper shell.
Is that possible somehow?

### or

Do the same idea, but to create a copy of the current script in a new temp script:

```
cat $0 > temp.sh
```

Then the main script will execute temp.sh, after the script finishes, it catches the copy of temp.sh back to the main script and removes temp.sh.
I think this works in theory, but I'm sure there is some easier way.

> **NOTE:** This is not about EOL particularly, I have some scripts that I
> need to apply same functionality to.

**Example of usage:**
The project involves running the script on windows and linux, if any user opened the script by editor on Windows, it will save the EOL to windows format which is '\n\r', this will give this error on windows:

```
./script.sh: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `$'{\r''
'/script.sh: line 5: `foo(){
```

And that's why i used sed in the beginning of the script.

Comment: I don't see the point why a script should modify itself (what is the expected outcome), but in any case, never do it, because the outcome is undefined. Bash does not necessarily (and AFIK usually indeed does not) read first the whole script into memory, but may load parts of it later, having remembered only the position in the file where to continue.

Comment: I've added the case as an update to the ticket. If the user changed the EOL on windows it will give an error.

Answer (score 0):

Do not change the currently running script.

Once I had a very slow script and during executing I started to tweak it to prepare for the next execution. It started to behave very strangely. It seems to me bash only reads the beginning of the script and reads the other parts later. So it was not  a problem at the beginning when my script was short but as my script became longer it started to cause problems.

Comment: That's true, because bash always proceeds the first line with no troubles and that's why i added the snippet i mentioned on top of it. But I was looking for something more practical than my solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could extend your current attempt:

```
[[ -z "$CANARY" ]] && { sed -i -e 's/\r$//g' "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"; CANARY=1 exec "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"; }
```

Essentially, you test for some variable, do your modification and then re-exec using the modified source while setting the variable.

You could also `source` it instead of `exec`ing, and not modify the actual script file:

```
[[ -z "$CANARY" ]] && { CANARY=1 source <(sed 's/\r$//g' "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"); exit }
```

Comment: I will try this, but I'm trying to find a cleaner way than commenting the line after exit. Because some of the users actually pushed the commented version to the repo, and troubles occurred.

Comment: @Sam why comment anything? With the exit, the script should never reach the line after unless it was already processed

Comment: the problem is after the bash succesfully finishes the first line a nd already has executed 'sed', the new modified version of the script won't be taking any affect and it will raise the error. Then user should run it again and it will run ok. So the user should run the script twice. 

What I was looking for some other cleaner way to open script, it updates it self, saves the context, then execute the body.